# How can I override the kernel default options for mount?

Tags: mount, linux-kernel, uuid

I'm struggling with a program that creates a file system in a file and mounts it as a loopback device. The purpose of the program is to create a clone of the root file system and it thinks it's being all smart by also copying over the UUID of the block device. However because I'm using XFS, the loopback mount fails because of the duplicated UUID value.

I can manually mount using `mount -o nouuid`, but the program re-creates the device and tries to mount it itself. Because it's not using fstab, I can't set the default mount options there.

Is there a way I can tell the kernel what the default options are when running mount and set the `nouuid` option so that even a `mount` command called without specifically specifying that option will use it?

Comment: A known commercial software? Is the program using `/[s]bin/mount` explicitly, or the one found in the `PATH`?

Comment: @enzotib I see where you're going with that. It looks like it's using `$PATH`, so I should be able to write a little wrapper script for it. It's ugly as heck so I'd still like to know if there is a way to set the defaults, but thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2):

For the generic options applicable to every file system, the [kernel](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.10.7/fs/namespace.c#L2261) applies the mount options that are passed to the `mount` system call to it as an array of boolean flags, it does not have any built-in defaults.

For xfs, the kernel [parses options](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.10.7/fs/xfs/xfs_super.c#L224) on top of built-in defaults ([all bits zero](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.10.7/fs/xfs/xfs_super.c#L1416) for boolean flags).

So you need to arrange to pass the right options to the `mount` system call. If your program calls the `mount` program, you can write a wrapper that changes the options on the fly.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$(ps -p $PPID -o comm=)" = "annoying-program" ]; then
  case "$* " in
    *" -t xfs "*) set -- -o nouuid "$@";;
  esac
fi
exec /sbin/mount "$@"
```

Put this script before `mount` in your PATH, or if the program hard-codes the path to `mount`, temporarily move `mount` to a different location and put the script in its place.

If your program calls the `mount` system call directly, you can [override the call via `LD_PRELOAD`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892162/what-are-the-possible-ways-of-intercepting-system-calls-on-unix-environments).